# Como migrar para a nova versão do Realm

Tags: android, android-adapter, realmdb

Olá, tenho um app simples do meu site de notícias, o encontrei no GitHub há algum tempo e editei.

Porem ele deixou de funcionar em alguns dispositivos (Android 5.1 pra cima) quando foi a correção descobri que com as ultimas atualizações do Android Studio não é mais possível usar a versão do realm que eu usava

> classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'

pois o android-apt ficou obsoleto e nesta versão (1.2.0) o mesmo é usado.

Tentei atualizar para a versão 4.3.3 do Realm porem o construtor utilizado na primeira vez mudou.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   mInstance = this;
    // init realm database
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("wordpress.realm")
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Então preciso de ajuda para adequar o código acima nas novas formas

*Sou um aventureiro no mundo de desenvolvimento Android, não tenho formação na área toda ajuda é bem-vinda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver se referindo a como atualizar o gradle do Android Studio você pode encontrar as informações aqui:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Se você está se referindo a fazer uma migration, você precisa buscar a respeito de realm migration. Essa migration é relacionado a trocar a versão do seu banco de dados, isso ocorre mudando o `schemaVersion(0)` por exemplo para `.schemaVersion(1)` dai sua migração é necessária.

Você usou  `.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`
Se você muda a versao do banco com essa linha você apaga as informações da versão anterior(definida pelo schemaVersion). Então seu banco de dados fica zerado e caso você precise alguma informação prévia o app irá da crash.

O link abaixo explica como fazer um migration.

https://medium.com/@budioktaviyans/android-realm-migration-schema-4fcef6c61e82